# Unknown app crash - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following function that gets called in my viewController's viewDidLoad:

```
fileprivate func setupScrollView(){
    //this will be the height of the image on this ViewController
    var imageHeight = ScreenSize.height() - 195 // replace with a relative calculation
    if ScreenSize.model() == .iphoneX{
        imageHeight = ScreenSize.height() * 0.58
    }
    self.dressImageScrollViewHeight.constant = imageHeight

    //now determine the image width based on height
    let scale = imageHeight / (self.item?.thumbnailSize?["height"] as? CGFloat ?? 1)
    let newWidth = (self.item?.thumbnailSize?["width"] as? CGFloat ?? 0) * scale
    self.imageScrollView.contentSize.width = newWidth + 20

    self.imageScrollView.contentInset.left = 10
    self.imageScrollView.contentInset.right = 20
    self.imageScrollView.contentOffset.x = -10

    guard self.firstImage != nil else{return}
    //this is the imageView for the first image
    // utilizes the preview image used on the cell in the previous view controller collection
    let firstImageView = PFImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: imageHeight))
    firstImageView.image = self.firstImage
    self.imageScrollView.imageViews.append(firstImageView)
    self.imageScrollView.addSubview(firstImageView)
}
```

Basically, I have something similar to a master detail view going on.  When in the master view, the a cell is selected, it goes to this detail view that has a collection for images.  The image used in the master view controller's cell for that item is passed over and is appended as the first image in the detail's image collection.

Recently, I've seen an influx in the number of crashes related to this code, by like a lot.  I am pretty sure it has to do with the last few lines of the function.

Below is the insights that my Crashlytics provides.

[image]

The thing is, the Crashlytics logs point to that guard statement as the issue, except I can't at all re-create this issue, but it is certainly happening to my users, as these crash reports are coming in all the time now.

Parse's PFImageView: https://github.com/parse-community/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUI/Classes/Views/PFImageView.m

Comment: Can say for sure but somewhere in your code you are applying CGAfflineTransform to a layer or view which cause division by zero. Dont know what is PFImageView. But maybe it is causing the crash.

Comment: @Mohammadalijf PFImageView is Parse

Comment: Might depend on how "image scroll view" works. But you have not shown that.

Comment: I will recommend you to put a exception breakpoint and check so to get more clarity of the line in code